# How to make a function a valid jax type?

Tags: jax

When I pass an object created using the following function function into a jax.lax.scan function:

```py
def logdensity_create(model, centeredness = None, varname = None):
    if centeredness is not None:
        model = reparam(model, config={varname: LocScaleReparam(centered= centeredness)})
          
    init_params, potential_fn_gen, *_ = initialize_model(jax.random.PRNGKey(0),model,dynamic_args=True)
    logdensity = lambda position: -potential_fn_gen()(position)
    initial_position = init_params.z
    return (logdensity, initial_position)
```

I get the following error (on passing the logdensity to an iterative function created using jax.lax.scan):

```
TypeError: Value .logdensity_create.. at 0x13fca7d80> with type  is not a valid JAX type
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: The ideas in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/1443) are probably helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably do this via [`jax.tree_util.Partial`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.tree_util.Partial.html), which wraps callables in a PyTree for compatibility with `jit` and other transformations:

```py
logdensity = jax.tree_util.Partial(lambda position: -potential_fn_gen()(position))
```

Comment: The flexibility between JIT and AOT is a fantastic feature of JAX. Is the Partial function cached if passed to several JIT'ed functions?